# How the same type of objects cout, cerr, clog perform differently?

Tags: c++, iostream

```
extern ostream cout;
extern ostream cerr;
extern ostream clog;
```

cout, cerr and clog are declared the type of ostream. But cout and clog have buffers but cerr does not.

How come the same type of objects behaves differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three objects have the same type, but they are not the same instance. Instances of `ostream` could be configured differently; in this case, the three objects are configured to deal with buffering each in its specific way. This makes sense: if all objects of the same class behaved in the same exact way, there would be no reason to make them separate objects in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/) takes a `streambuf` option

`explicit ostream (streambuf * sb);`

Im guessing each of them use different `streambuf` outputs, and those `streambuf` objects control how the output is buffered(or not).